# ng-circle-progress component only works when property renderOnClick atribute is set to true

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

when i use the ng-circle-component on my web browser with te "renderOnClick" property set to false, it appear as if the component percent is 0. Only setting this property as true, does it load when clicked as it should given the property. All other properties work fine, including the predefined ones.

This is for a ionic app created with the latest ionic (5.2.1), cordova is already installed (9.0.0) and npm is installed. Modifiying the forRoot function doesnt solve or affects the problem

this is my call to the component:

```
<circle-progress (click)="startTime()"
        [percent]="percent"
        [maxPercent]="100"
        [radius]="radius"
        [showTitle]="false"
        [showSubtitle]="false"
        [showUnits]="false"
        [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
        [outerStrokeColor]="'#239996'"
        [showZeroOuterStroke]="false"
        [backgroundStroke]="'#33003F'"
        [backgroundStrokeWidth]="3"
        [outerStrokeGradient]="true"
        [outerStrokeGradientStopColor]="'#FF00CB'"
        [showInnerStroke]="false"
    ></circle-progress>
```

where percent and radius are variables on my ts file

and here is the predefining of the component:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { NgCircleProgressModule } from 'ng-circle-progress';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]),
    NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
      // set defaults here
      radius: 100,
      percent:85,
      outerStrokeWidth: 16,
      innerStrokeWidth: 8,
      outerStrokeColor: "#CC0000",
      innerStrokeColor: "#C7E596",
      animationDuration:300,
      animation:false,
      responsive:true,
      renderOnClick:false
    })
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

i want the component to render to the desired percentage as soon as this changes (on another component or setted to a value like 85) but it only does render the percentage when the renderOnClick property is on

Answer (score 3):

Sometime, version update can be the cause of everything in a project standstill. I also encounter this for some days now and here is how I solved it by setting property `lazy: false` either in forRoot or in the html

```
NgCircleProgressModule.forRoot({
      ...
      lazy: false
    }),
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
```

the solution was found here 
https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress/issues/85